# Properties of polynomial in finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $f \in F_p[x]$.

Prove that polynomials $f(x), f(x + 1), \dotso, f(x + p - 1)$ are either pairwise distinct or they all coincide.

I think the right approach may involve Lagrange polynomials.

Comment: Maybe add finite field tag be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0<k<p$. Then
$$f(x)=f(x+k)$$
implies that
$$f(x)=f(x+ak)$$
for all $a\in \mathbb N$ (because $f(x+(a-1)k)=f((x+(a-1)k)+k)$, so we can use an inductive proof). For any $0\leq m<p$, there is an $a$ such that
$$ak\equiv m\pmod p$$
Thus $f(x)= f(x+m)$ for all $m$, and we are done.

Comment: Maybe you meant $f(x+(a-1)k)=f((x+(a-2)k)+k)$...?

Comment: @False No, that's not what I meant. You can add $k$ to anything in the parentheses without changing the polynomial, so $f(x+(a-1)k)=f(x+ak)$.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clear.

Comment: @False No problem.